# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use a scalar as an array warning

Tags: php, arrays, warnings, scalar

I have the following code:

```
 $final = [1 => 2];
 $id = 1;

 $final[$id][0] = 3;
```

The code seems to work fine, but I get this warning:

> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in line X (the
> line with: $final[$id][0] = 3).

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Reproducibles: [Cannot Use a Scalar Value as an Array, But Data Successfully Updated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34916007/2943403) and [PHP Error - Cannot use a scalar value as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31892296/2943403)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You need to set`$final[$id]` to an array before adding elements to it. Intiialize it with either

```
$final[$id] = array();
$final[$id][0] = 3;
$final[$id]['link'] = "/".$row['permalink'];
$final[$id]['title'] = $row['title'];
```

or

```
$final[$id] = array(0 => 3);
$final[$id]['link'] = "/".$row['permalink'];
$final[$id]['title'] = $row['title'];
```

Comment: You can simplify some lines in the first case to `$final[$id][] = 3;` and in the second to `$final[$id] = array(3);` :)

Comment: @Tadeck yes you can, I thought I would be explicit though ; )

Comment: This solution solved my problem, but the "why" of it eludes me. PHP, as far as I've ever used it, doesn't require you to declare a variable's type. My code was working fine, and then it last night started spewing this error for some inexplicable reason, out of the clear blue sky. As a matter of course, in my MVC (CodeIgniter) code I routinely assign the $data = array() type at the top of my functions. In my plain jane php, I rarely do. In php, I don't think it's mandatory. Yet, declaring my variable as an array type solved my problem. Perplexed.

Answer (score 97):

The reason is because somewhere you have first declared your variable with a normal integer or string and then later you are trying to turn it into an array.

Answer (score 3):

The Other Issue I have seen on this is when nesting arrays this tends to throw the warning, consider the following:

```
$data = [
"rs" => null
]
```

this above will work absolutely fine when used like:

```
$data["rs"] =  5;
```

But the  below will throw a warning ::

```
$data = [
    "rs" => [
       "rs1" => null;
       ]
    ]
..

$data[rs][rs1] = 2; // this will throw the warning unless assigned to an array
```

Comment: I think in this case it's because you forgot to quote the `rs` and `rs1` on the last line.  That makes them undefined constants, and so `$data[rs]` is not defined.

Answer (score -1):

Also make sure that you don't declare it an array and then try to assign something else to the array like a string, float, integer.  I had that problem.  If you do some echos of output I was seeing what I wanted the first time, but not after another pass of the same code.