# Storing multiple data in Sqlite from Mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite

I want to store data of particular user from `mysql` to `sqlite`. I am only able to recieve only one row of particular user.

Here is my code.

**login**

```
JSONObject jsonexercise = userFunction.exerciseItems(name);

try {
    System.out.println(" exe try");
    if (jsonexercise.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
        String result = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
        System.out.println(" exersise result" + result);
        if(Integer.parseInt(result) == 1){
            System.out.println("exercise inside parse");
            JSONObject json_exercisedata = json.getJSONObject("getexercise");
            db.exerciseItem(json_exercisedata.getString(KEY_ENAME),json_exercisedata.getString(KEY_EXERCISE_NAME),json_exercisedata.getString(KEY_DURATION),json_exercisedata.getString(KEY_CALORIE_BURNED),json_exercisedata.getString(KEY_ECREATED_AT));
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("no exercise item to show");
    }
}
catch (JSONException e) {
System.out.println("no exerc item to show");

}
```

**userfunction**

```
public JSONObject exerciseItems(String name){
    // Building Parameters

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", get_exetag));

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    System.out.println("in json object name" + name);

    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject jsonexercise = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(insertURL, params);
    // return json
    return jsonexercise;
}
```

**dbhandler**

```
public void exerciseItem(String name, String exercisename,String duration, String calorieburned, String created_at) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
    System.out.println("in db handler insert user the name is" + name);
    values.put(KEY_EXERCISENAME, exercisename); // Email
    values.put(KEY_DURATION, duration); 
    values.put(KEY_CALORIE_BURNED, calorieburned);
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(EXERCISE_ITEM, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

**php**

```
public function getExeciseitems($name) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT name,exercisename,duration,calorieburned,created_at FROM exercisedata WHERE name = '$name'") or die(mysql_error());
    // check for result 
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        return $result;
    } else {
        // user not found
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you got your user from mysql, the problem is?

Comment: i am having more then 10 rows in mysql of particular user. I am only able to see one in my json response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                return $result;

        } else {
            // user not found
            return false;
        }
```

Does not work because you have more than one record extracted.
You need to loop like this:

```
if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 $result[] = $row;
}
return $result;
}else {
                // user not found
                return false;
            }
```

The code is untested.

Edit: to avoid that error this link [PHP - cannot use a scalar as an array warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019853/php-cannot-use-a-scalar-as-an-array-warning)
Say to use:

```
if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    $result = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     $result[$i] = array();
     $result[$i] = $row;
     $i++;
    }
    return $result;
    }else {
                    // user not found
                    return false;
                }
```

I've added a counter for populating. ($i)

edit2: changed the name:

```
if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        $i = 0;
        $result2 = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
         $result2[$i] = array();
         $result2[$i] = $row;
         $i++;
        }
        return $result2;
        }else {
                        // user not found
                        return false;
                    }
```

Comment: PHP - cannot use a scalar as an array warning. But the good thing is it showing me the error as much time the record is available in database. What to do now ?

Comment: again same error on 
$result[$i] = $row;
$i++;

Comment: after $i =0; you can add a line which says: $result = array();

Comment: It says 
mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in /home/bharatwellness/public_html/DB_Functions.php on line 73

Comment: @pratz9999 Change the $result used inside the $no_of_rows if with another name (updated the answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66739/discussion-between-pratz9999-and-marco-mura).