# PHP Error - Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello I am a beginner in codeigniter framework and I have some problems.

On my index page i have login form, and when user insert username and password and clicks submit button he calls controller's method login whose task is to collect username and password from form and to pass the data to models method "login($username, $password)" and then models method returns true or false depending on whether we have valid user in database or not, and then controller's method either  pass the user further or returns him on the beginning.
My problem is that i want to know users access level, and i made this method in model

```
public function users_level($username){

    $query = $this->db->get_where('users',array('username' => $username) );

    $users_level = $query->result();    // I tried with these too $users_level[] = $query->result();    

    return $users_level;
}
```

with which i want to return user's access level, and to use that information in order to determine what view to present for that specific user.

This is login method from controller:

```
public function login(){
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $this->load->model('model_user');
        $result = $this->model_user->login($username,$password);
        if ($result == true){     
                $result['level'] = $this->model_user->users_level($username);    //i believe that mistake is maybe in this line
                $this->welcome();   //I'm going to send information to welcome method about users level of access                  
            }else if ($result == false){
                $this->index();
            }
}
```

And this is an error that occurs

```
Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Filename: controllers/controler_user.php

Line Number: 33

Backtrace:

File: C:\wamp\www\ci_project_2015\application\controllers\controler_user.php
Line: 33
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\wamp\www\ci_project_2015\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

Comment: Look, you have `$result == true` and then `$result['level'] = ...`. So, what is this `$result` - a boolean or an array?

Comment: Just a suggestion: CodeIgniter is dead and any skilled PHP-developer would tell you that this is a one of the worst PHP frameworks. Why don't use better frameworks like Laravel, Silex?

Comment: @DavidY this isn't the forum to suggest alternative frameworks. And even if it is "dead", there are still existing systems written in CodeIgniter which need maintenance.

Comment: @topher He said he's a beginner, so better not to start with a one of the terrible frameworks. Also, comments themselves are about suggestions and asking for details.

Comment: first result returns true or false and we use that variable to enter either in if, or else condition, and other result variable i use to store data that i want to retrieve from db , about user level - for that user who login on the system.
So first result variable is not important after i enter in if or else statement. And the reason why i need to learn codeigniter is because i need to pass the test on my college

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use `$result` as an array when it is already initialized as a boolean. You could reinitialize it as an array using:

```
$result = array('level' => $this->model_user->users_level($username));
```

or

```
$result = array();
$result['level'] = $this->model_user->users_level($username);
```

**However**, this is a bad idea since you are using the same variable for different things. A better solution is to rename one of the variables e.g.

```
$logged_in = $this->model_user->login($username,$password);
if ($logged_in == true){
```

Or better yet, since the boolean is only being used once, you can skip the initialization of `$logged_in` and use the result of `$this->model_user->login($username,$password)` directly in the condition

```
if ($this->model_user->login($username,$password)) {
```

You can omit the `== true` since it returns a boolean.

Comment: I thought it would overwrite the first variable, and it doesn't matter whether a variable have the same name because we no longer need the first information.
And now that I've changed the name,there are no more problems. Thank you very much, I appreciate your help.