# Cannot Use a Scalar Value as an Array, But Data Successfully Updated

Tags: php

I have this code :

```
public function updateSegmentGender ($product_id, $segment_gender) {

    $this->connect();
    $product_id = $this->escapeString($product_id);

    $row_count = count($segment_gender);

    for ($row = 0; $row < $row_count; $row++) {

        $this->select('product_seg_gender', '*', NULL, 
                      'product_id = "'.$product_id.'" AND gender = "'.$segment_gender[$row][0].'"', NULL, NULL);
        $res = $this->getResult();
        $res = count($res);

        $gender = $segment_gender[$row][0];
        $status = $segment_gender[$row][1];

        if ($res <> 0) {
            // UPDATE
            $data = array ('status'=>$status);
            $this->update('product_seg_gender', $data, 'product_id = "'.$product_id.'" AND gender = "'.$gender.'"');
        }else {
            // INSERT
            $data = array ('product_id'=>$product_id, 'gender'=>$gender, 'status'=>$status);
            $this->insert('product_seg_gender', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm using that method like this :

```
$user = new Product($db_server, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
$user->connect();

$segment_gender = array ( array ("all", "active"),
                          array ("female", "active"));

$res = $user->updateSegmentGender ('303', $segment_gender);
print_r($res);
```

but why I always got this error message :

```
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in /home/***/public_html/class/Database.class.php on line 130
```

however, the database is successfully updated. what did I do wrong?

UPDATE : here's complete line 97-145 of Database.class.php

```
// Function to SELECT from the database
public function select($table, $rows = '*', $join = null, $where = null, $order = null, $limit = null){
    // Create query from the variables passed to the function
    $q = 'SELECT '.$rows.' FROM '.$table;
    if($join != null){
        $q .= ' JOIN '.$join;
    }
    if($where != null){
        $q .= ' WHERE '.$where;
    }
    if($order != null){
        $q .= ' ORDER BY '.$order;
    }
    if($limit != null){
        $q .= ' LIMIT '.$limit;
    }
    // echo $table;
    $this->myQuery = $q; // Pass back the SQL
    // Check to see if the table exists
    if($this->tableExists($table)){
        // The table exists, run the query
        $query = $this->myconn->query($q);    
        if($query){
            // If the query returns >= 1 assign the number of rows to numResults
            $this->numResults = $query->num_rows;
            // Loop through the query results by the number of rows returned
            for($i = 0; $i < $this->numResults; $i++){
                $r = $query->fetch_array();
                $key = array_keys($r);
                for($x = 0; $x < count($key); $x++){
                    // Sanitizes keys so only alphavalues are allowed
                    if(!is_int($key[$x])){
                        if($query->num_rows >= 1){
                            $this->result[$i][$key[$x]] = $r[$key[$x]];
                        }else{
                            $this->result[$i][$key[$x]] = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true; // Query was successful
        }else{
            array_push($this->result,$this->myconn->error);
            return false; // No rows where returned
        }
    }else{
        return false; // Table does not exist
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no return in the function?

Comment: What is _line 130_ code? also use **return $data;** at last line into _updateSegmentGender_ function

Comment: @Pooya : is that what cause the error message? because I tried to remove `print_r($res);` from my code, I still get the error.

Comment: I'm not sure try returning $res in the function and see what happens without returning $res, the function doesn't do anything useful

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd : please check my update, above. I put complete lines of the class.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois : please check my update, just posted.

Comment: @Pooya : surprisingly... by adding `return $res;` on my updateSegmentGender removed the error message. not sure how it works. but it's gone now.

Comment: It looks like you are using MySQLi or PDO (I hope you don't use mysql_* anymore), so I will give you this freebie: Use Prepared Statements with binding parameters. Escaping is so 2005.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois : thanks for your comment. but, I'm using this class for database connection : https://github.com/rorystandley/MySQLi-CRUD-PHP-OOP, not sure it's compatible with 'Prepared Statements' or not...

Comment: No, it's not. You should use a different class (or write your own), as it is not secure. Meanwhile you can upgrade to PDO

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to return something in order to fix your warning (unless you really need it)  from the function like UpdateSomething. I think the problem is in this: $res = $this->getResult(); $res = count($res); You use one variable as an array and as an integer. You should separate them. and you should also exactly declare all you variables in the code. like $res = array(); $count = $count($res); and so on.

Comment: @SergeyAn : I tried to change `$res = $this->getResult();` and `$res = count($res);` lines with this : `$res = $this->getResult();` and `$count = count($res);`, then remove the `return $res;`. The error still appears.

Comment: @SergeyAn : by the way, you wrote `$count = $count($res);`. Isn't that `$count = count($res);` ?

Comment: Yes. It was a general point. Not the exact code. Try to do this: $count = count($this->getResult()); and remove your $res variable. In the if condition also use $count. If you want to test your function using print_r then you have to return some data from your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I hope you require `$res = $user->updateSegmentGender ('303', $segment_gender);` need `$data` value and based on assumption I use `$data` for return part.

Perhaps due to `$data` not initialized. I'm trying to declaring the variable `$data`, as an array, before using it I also make another change that `function updateSegmentGender()` require *return* part so I put this.

```
public function updateSegmentGender ($product_id, $segment_gender) {

    $this->connect();
    $product_id = $this->escapeString($product_id);

    $row_count = count($segment_gender);

    $data = array();//Initialize variable...
    for ($row = 0; $row < $row_count; $row++) {

        $this->select('product_seg_gender', '*', NULL, 
                      'product_id = "'.$product_id.'" AND gender = "'.$segment_gender[$row][0].'"', NULL, NULL);
        $res = $this->getResult();
        $res = count($res);

        $gender = $segment_gender[$row][0];
        $status = $segment_gender[$row][1];

        if ($res <> 0) {
            // UPDATE
            $data = array ('status'=>$status);
            $this->update('product_seg_gender', $data, 'product_id = "'.$product_id.'" AND gender = "'.$gender.'"');
        }else {
            // INSERT
            $data = array ('product_id'=>$product_id, 'gender'=>$gender, 'status'=>$status);
            $this->insert('product_seg_gender', $data);
        }
    }
    //Return funal value in array format...
    return $data;
}
```